# Error message 'Cannot find module...' when running 'yarn dev' with Node 16.14 and Yarn 1.22.29

Tags: node.js

I have some trouble with Next.js and `yarn dev`.

Every time I run the project it shows this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLf5y.png)

When I run build the error is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D41VM.png)

I use node 16.14 and yarn 1.22.29

Comment: Please share error messages as text. [ask]